# Pip disappeared and get-pip.py won't reinstall it

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install numpy through pip. I was getting an error that it couldn't find some file (unfortunately I didn't copy the error)

I'm honestly not sure what I did after that, but pip wanted to update. Then I got another error and when checking the Scripts folder, pip had completely disappeared.

Since then I've tried several times to reinstall pip through get-pip.py. There's always the same error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
    Found existing installation: pip 21.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.3.1
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip-21.3.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~-p-21.3.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\
   from C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~~p
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] Can't find the file: 'C:\\Python39\\Scripts\\pip.exe' -> 'C:\\Python39\\Scripts\\pip.exe.deleteme'

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

So it finds some version of pip, tries to uninstall it but then can't install pip because there is no pip.exe in the Scripts folder...? I apologise I can't describe my steps before this, I'm a noob with these things and I honestly can't remember the different things I did :^)

Also, if it matters, python is in my PATH already. My python version is 3.9.6

Answer (score 0):

There exist [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) built-in module which

> In most cases, end users of Python shouldn’t need to invoke this
> module directly (as `pip` should be bootstrapped by default), but it
> may be needed if installing `pip` was skipped when installing Python
> (or when creating a virtual environment) or after explicitly
> uninstalling `pip`.

Please try use it as follows: open terminal and do

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Comment: Hmm this is what I get when I use it: 
`C:\Users\varga>python -m ensurepip WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) Looking in links: c:\Users\varga\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqz_fmjou Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (56.0.0) Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (21.3.1) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)`

Comment: @Kida what happens when you try `python -m pip`?

Comment: Hmm Usage, commands and general options appear

Comment: @Kida so it seems that it is working, please try installing some external package for example `python -m pip install requests` and check if it did what it should

Comment: Hmm, not sure. It says it installed it but it also repeated this warning several times: `WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)`

Comment: @Kida please check if it was actually installed by running simple file which has two line, one `import requests` second `print(requests.__version__)`. If it will show version that means you have working if noisy pip installed.